# Two very similar pieces of c code, one works one does not work, why?

Tags: c, network-programming, libevent

I have two different programs. Both should connect to another program and send a bit of text to it, and then get the same echoed back to them. When I run them one of them works fine (my echo server reports what it received, and the program reacts to what was sent back), the other one doesn't work (i have print statements before and after the statement that should sent the text, both print to the screen but connecting to the same echo server, the server never receives the data, it will still verify the connections but never receives  the data).

The working code is:

```
struct addrinfo *server;
struct addrinfo hints = {};
char ipAddr[16], portNum[6];
bool portNow = false;
int i = 0; 
int j = 0; 
for (i = 0; servList->monitor[i] != '\0'; ) {
 /* successfully parses text in servList->monitor into two strings ipAddr and portNum
*/ }
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_protocol = 0; 
getaddrinfo("localhost", portNum, &hints, &server);
servList->b_monitor = bufferevent_socket_new(eBase, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE); 
bufferevent_setcb(servList->b_monitor, monitorRead, NULL, NULL, servList); 
if(bufferevent_socket_connect(servList->b_monitor, server->ai_addr, server->ai_addrlen) != 0) { /* reports error */} 
bufferevent_enable(servList->b_monitor, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);
bufferevent_write(servList->b_monitor, servList->name, sizeof(servList->name));
```

servList is a pointer to a structure with a member name[30], servList is pointer to the linked list of structures used by the call back function monitorRead. I took out the error handling from this code with is not triggered when it runs anyway. eBase is the event base passed into the function where this resides.

The code that doesn't work is:

```
int n;
char buffer [256];
struct event_base *base;
struct addrinfo *server;
struct addrinfo hints = {};
struct bufferevent *client;
char portNum[6] = "4044";
base = event_base_new();
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_protocol = 0;
getaddrinfo("localhost", portNum, &hints, &server); 
client = bufferevent_socket_new(base, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE); 
bufferevent_setcb(client, clientRead, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if(bufferevent_socket_connect(client, serverTwo->ai_addr, serverTwo->ai_addrlen) != 0) { 
 /* reports error */
} 
bufferevent_enable(client, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer, 255, stdin); 
printf("buffer to send: %s\n", buffer);
bufferevent_write(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 
printf("after bufferevent write\n");
```

Buffer is a different size than servList->name but both are char [] type, client is the same type as servList->b_monitor. The read in is working since it prints to the screen before calling bufferevent_write(). Neither code generates any warnings or errors from the compiler the second simple seems to ignore the bufferevent_write() statement.

I have been going over the code with a fine tooth comb, and poring through the libevent man pages, etc but I can't figure out what I have made different in the second piece of code so that it doesn't work. I am working on Mac os X, if that makes a difference. If I am leaving out any important information let me know and I will edit it in.

Edit: port number info. during my tests both programs have been using the same port number

Comment: Might the firewall on your host be blocking portNum 4044?

Comment: N.B. check the manpage for fgets(), you're wasting a whole byte. Make that `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);` and `bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));`.

Comment: I will add the info to the main question above, but they are both using the same port number. I can change the port number from a config file on the first but I have been using the same port number on my tests.

Comment: You're writing 256 bytes to the server, even if the input is only 10 bytes. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Barmar Yea, this program is only for testing another program, so I am not worried about things like that, but I do need to make it work. If I need to test larger or smaller byte sizes I can change it in the program itself, but for 256 bytes I haven't bothered.